# Removing "Hints" from Inspection Results window in Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, resharper-6.0, resharper-7.1

with previous versions of Resharper we used to do a "Find Code Issues" command before doing a check-in. Now we updated from 6 to Resharper 7.1 and that command is showing the Hints as issues (we normally don't hide anything but set unneeded inspection items to Hint as maybe they are useful to someone as we are a somewhat big team).

Is there a way so "Find Code Issues" only spots real issues and does not show Hints? We used to see 0 issues and now 570 Hints appear as if something is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a feature request you can comment on and vote for: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-216644

Comment: Thanks. I will vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed by the Resharper team that this is not possible :(